# Rethinkdb join with filter

Tags: rethinkdb

I am experimenting with rethinkdb and I was wondering what's the best way to convert the following SQL query to ReQL.

```
SELECT requests.id, users.name FROM requests JOIN users 
    ON requests.userid = users.id and users.valid_until IN NULL
```

Basically I have an insert only table for users, where I set the valid_until date on the row something changes and make a copy with the changed value in a new row.

I would like to get a list of all the requests together with the user name of the user who made the request, based on the last version of the 'user' object.

I tried:

```
r.table('requests').eq_join(
   r.row['webob_adhoc_attrs']['id'],
   r.table('users')
    .filter(lambda user: not user.has_fields('valid_until')), 
   index='id').run(conn)
```

But it doesn't work, obviously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using Python's `not` but you should be using `~` at the beginning or `.not_()` at the end of the ReQL query.

https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/not/

The problem that I haven't come across myself is that one cannot perform a filter within an `eq_join` because of conflicting overlapping index use within the `eq_join` statement. Either of these options should work:

#### Option 1 - perform the filter afterwards:

```
r.table('requests').eq_join(
    r.row['webob_adhoc_attrs']['id'],
    r.table("users")
  )\
  .filter(lambda row: ~row.has_fields('valid_until')\
  .run(conn)
```

#### Option 2 - perform the filter before:

Since the first parameter to `eq_join` seeks to match the result of the index per document on the second table we have to create a new index. Basically we are trying to match if `table('users')['id'] == document in the index for table('requests)`

```
# Create index first because of the embedded id field
r.table('requests').index_create('requests_id', r.row['webob_adhoc_attrs']['id'])
# Then can properly join on filtered
r.table('users').filter(\
    lambda row: ~row.has_fields('valid_until'))\
    .eq_join( 
      r.row['id'],
      r.table('requests'),
      index = 'requests_id'
    )
```

Then to take it one step further, `.filter` cannot use an index. But, you can use `.get_all` with an index to make it faster.

```
r.table("requests")\
   .index_create('not_has_valid_until', ~r.row.has_fields('valid_until'))

r.table("requests")\
   .get_all(r.expr(True), index='not_has_valid_until')\
   .eq_join( 
     r.row['id'],
     r.table('requests'),
     index = 'requests_id'
   )
```

I tested the finer parts of this locally, but obviously don't have your same dataset. Option 1 is very succinct and readable, but I would estimate that you'd get better performance on a large dataset with option 2, on my small test dataset, the results were pretty much the same using RethinkDB 2.3.

Hope that clears it up for you! Come ask questions at [slack.rethinkdb.com](http://slack.rethinkdb.com) in #help (and find me @dalanmiller) if you need more detailed assistance!

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I now get rethinkdb.errors.ReqlServerCompileError: Cannot use r.row in nested queries.  Use functions instead in:
r.table('requests').eq_join(lambda var_2: r.row['webob_adhoc_attrs']['userid'], lambda var_3: r.table('users').filter(lambda var_1: (~r.row.has_fields('valid_until'))), index='uuid')

Comment: Thanks again. And sorry for keep bothering you. Now I get the same error I was getting with my version: "rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type TABLE but found SELECTION:". Is filter maybe not supported during joins?

Comment: Consulted with the RethinkDB lead engineer, and gave this some more testing. Let me know if one of these works for you!